# Trying to add a new product variant(Original Price) to products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, spree

I've been into java for more than 5 years, and now into Rails so I am relatively new to this so please bear with me if this sounds naive. I am using Spree to create an online store.I am trying to add a new product variant called Original Price. The aim is to show the price of the product along with the striked out original price in products page.

So I've created a new migration and added a new column to spree_variants table.

```
class AddOriginalPriceToProductsModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  add_column :spree_variants, :original_price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
 end
end
```

and added a corresponding field in Admin form as well. Now I've been struck for a while in creating the Variants decorator part. I've added a variants decorator as follows,

```
Spree::Variant.class_eval do
  before_filter :load_data
  attr_accesssible :original_price
end
```

but this doesn't solve the purpose. 
I came close to doing this from [Extending the Spree::Product model/class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202851/extending-the-spreeproduct-model-class) .Also I am not able to get the details that I want from the the Spree document with my little understanding.
Can someone please point me in the right direction of doing this or is there any better alternate way.

**Environment**,

- **Rails** : 3.2.13
- **Spree** : 2.0.3

also using **spree_fancy** theme

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Override the existing classes. if you are using spree 2-0-stable then your relative path will be app/models/frontend and same for backend.

For further assistance see [this](http://ryanbigg.com/spree-guides/logic_customization.html)