# unexpected keyword_end when add new attribute to spree model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I want to add a new attribute "usertype" to User. I followed the answer in the following link:

[Extending the Spree::Product model/class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202851/extending-the-spreeproduct-model-class)

I created a new migration and also created a file "spree/user_decorator.rb", which has the codes:

```
Spree::User.class_eval
  attr_accesssible :usertype
end
```

But when I run "rails s", it says I have "syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)" in this file.

What's wrong with the three lines of codes?

PS: I also tried

```
Spree::User.class_eval do
  attr_accesssible :usertype
end
```

Then it says the method attr_accesssible does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code sample is syntactically incorrect. Your second code sample is the correct syntax.

attr_accessible is no longer used in Rails 4, which is used by Spree 2.1 and later. You should look in to adding the attribute to Spree's [PermittedAttributes](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/322a39e59f177322d2ec4d9a16aebe4d4714e8b8/core/lib/spree/permitted_attributes.rb#L98) instead.